# Trouble loading fontawesome icon using CDN

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome, cdn

I'm having difficulties loading Font Awesome icons on my website when using a CDN. The icons don't appear, and I suspect it's due to a font loading issue. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Included the Font Awesome CSS file from a CDN using the <link> tag.
- Ensured that the CSS file is properly linked and accessible.
- Wrapped the icons in a <div> with the appropriate class and added the necessary CSS styles.

Despite these steps, the icons still won't show up. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can I know which framework you are using here ?

Comment: I am using react here @ShraddhaGoel

Comment: if you recently added CDN in index.html, try restarting the app

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check your browser's developer console for errors?

Comment: The only problem is I was getting squares instead of font @NicoHaase

Comment: And why did that happen? Did you use the wrong URL to load the CSS file? Please check your browser's developer console for this

Comment: As Nico said, check in Developer Console that the files were loaded (look at the Network tab for the requests of the FA ressources). Also, just so that we can eliminate common reasons for trouble, it would be helpful to see the actual HTML you used to load FA and a sample of using it.